# unattended-upgrades ignoring origins

Tags: ubuntu, unattended-upgrades

I would like unattended-upgrades to upgrade security packages only, hence I configured /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades as follows:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security"; 
//       "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates"; 
//       "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed"; 
//       "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports"; 
};
```

But unattended-upgrades appears to ignore the configuration file and updates more than a=xenial-security':

> Unattended-upgrades log: Initial blacklisted packages:  Initial
>   whitelisted packages:  Starting unattended upgrades script Allowed
>   origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security'] Packages that will be
>   upgraded: libgraphite2-3 libmspack0 Writing dpkg log to
>   '/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log' All
>   upgrades installed

Why is unattended-upgrades not limiting itself to security patches?

Comment: https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/ : looks like `libgraphite2-3` and `libmspack0` have had security issues 2 days ago. So, the output of unattended-upgrades looks good to me.

Comment: The formatting of your post seems to be broken. You probably meant to format as code blocks rather than block quotes. Unless you fix the formatting, it is hard to tell for sure which lines in your post are commented out and which ones are not.